Trouble reading a file with C++ in vs code, not sure if this is because I'm working within Linux
Im trying to read the contents of a file in C++, but when I go to run the program it keeps failing. Not sure if this is because I'm using ubuntu linux.
Code below: seems basic enough but for some reason the file never opens and continues to fail
  // This program reads data from a file.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // Create a text string, which is used to output the text file
string myText;

// Read from the text file
ifstream MyReadFile;
MyReadFile.open("nums");

if(!MyReadFile){
  cout << "Failed" << endl;
}
else 

// Use a while loop together with the getline() function to read the file line by line
  while (getline (MyReadFile, myText)) {
  // Output the text from the file
    cout << myText;
  }

// Close the file
MyReadFile.close(); 
}


Your string has to include the complete directory plus the file extension type. For example in linux this might be "/home/user/files/nums.txt".

Is your file really named exactly nums with no extension? Is it in the current working directory? In VSCode that directory probably is the same one as the executable and your code.

The image of your code is unhelpful. An image of the folder may help solve the problem.

showing the code semi transparent over some other stuff is not very helpful in reading. And using a dark purple color on dark grey is hard to read.

Your file won't be open because you're missing the full path to it and the extension. If your file is in your "home" directory for example, you should write
MyReadFile.open("/home/nums.txt");

Here is another answer from stack overflow: How do you open a file in C++?

Note that the user's home directory will be /home/. Your typical user won't have permission to write in /home.

no need for an absolute path, a relative path is enough, much better is to use the file path as argument of the program
